# Get specific row from datatable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

How do I get only data for rows that is true for my condition: in the `dt.Rows[]` what do I specify so that it takes the row number of my resulting SQL query?

```
string sq = "select EmpName,contactnumber,dob,Address from tbl_emp_details where empname = @empname";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sq, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empname", comboBox1.SelectedText);

SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
// com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empname",Name.SelectedText);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);

Name.Text = dt.Rows[]["Empname"].ToString();
```

Comment: Are you looking for passing an index, like `dt.Rows[0]`?

Comment: Yes, but when i pass dt.Rows[0] it says you have now at position 0

Comment: Well, if your `SELECT` with the  `WHERE` clause doesn't match any rows, then of course, none are returned, so you cannot use `dt.Rows[0]` in that case.....

Comment: You should consider modernizing your data access approach.  Have a look here: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to check if row 0 even exists, use something like this:

```
Name.Text = dt.Rows.Count > 0 ? (string)dt.Rows[0]["Empname"] : null;
```

And don't use `ToString()` on something you know is a string, it's not only inefficient, but it shows you don't understand your framework.